# How to make smooth and beautiful path in google map api android?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I creaeted a map using the direction api and can be able to show on map but its not as smooth as the origional google map looks like.[image: Map showing path] 
is it the way so that i can make it like !
[google map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKAB6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can make it exactly the same since Gmaps (that's my idea) has access to more object than you...

Anyway, you can make your line a little bit better by modifying color and size of the polyline:
setWidth and setColor are your only friends for this task...
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline#setWidth(float)

Comment: I can't elaborate since I dont know any detail (as wrote, that's my idea). There are some classes that are marked as internal and are not accessible to "us" developers, I'm quite sure Google Maps application can instead access those classes

Comment: Ok though I did the same as you suggested. Thanks for answering.